# Given n and m, Solve for x : $n ^ x = 1\mod m$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, exponentiation, exponential-diophantine-equations

Given positive integers $n$ and $m$, Find the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $$n ^ x = 1\mod m$$

$m$ is not necessarily prime, So if $m = p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}p_{3}^{a_{3}}...p_{k}^{a_{k}}$,
I am looking for an algorithm with time complexity $O(a_1a_2a_3..a_k)$ or better.

Comment: Does this help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: $x$ is the order of $n$ modulo $m$ , determining it is in general difficult even if $m$ is prime since $m-1$ must be factored. Useful is that $x$ must divide $\varphi(m)$ and for the existence of $x$ we need of course $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Comment: @gist076923 Thanks. I think thats enough. merging